# Grails file upload with image name

Tags: grails, file-upload

I have a grails controller to handle uploaded files.

Now the problem is that i dont know by which name user will upload the file.

request.getFile(fileName)

I dont know the 'fileName'.

Please let me know how to handle anonymous file upload. These files are being uploaded from a javascript rich text editor and the name of the file input is comes different with each request.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should dump the `parmas` and inspect which is varible is holding the `filename` it might not be the varible filename holding the actual file name. so , if u dont have the file name you would have the file handle to proceeed uploading so do as follow :

1.DUMP parmas like

```
log.debug("Value of Parmas"+parmas.each{it.value()})
```

or

```
  println("Value of Parmas"+parmas.each{it.value()})
```

on your console window or what ever using the browser look for a common name that you will use further to get the file handle usually called 'filename'.

Comment: Another question.. How can I rename the file when I dont know its name and extenstion.. I have to append the timestamp value behind file name.. Like abc.txt -> abc_12312312.txt

Comment: @ManishMudgal you have a lots of option . you can append it with random string generatted of some sort or the time stamp simply

Comment: Show me params dump and i will assist you

Comment: Done that. It was just a restart away ;)